# I can't upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, upgrade

I got alot of errors while upgrading and the upgrading stopped. I can't open the update manager anymore.

```
tonkku@ubuntu:~$ update-manager -d

(update-manager:12524): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:62:17: Theming engine 'unico' not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 37, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.UpdateManager import UpdateManager
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 39, in <module>
    import dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ImportError: No module named _dbus_bindings
```

By the way, I used wubi to install ubuntu. Is that affecting it?

Comment: I'd suggest `sudo apt-get install dbus-python` (or `--reinstall`ing it if it is installed)

Answer (score 1):

You could always try the Ubuntu Server method of upgrading (which I use to upgrade desktops over SSH):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

---

Also, the `-d` flag is for upgrading to a development release. There simply isn't a development release that's a target from 12.10. 13.04 is your only upgrade path and that's released. By simply dropping the `-d` and using `-c` (to check for new releases), you might find it works:

```
update-manager -c
```

Comment: Thanks for now. it started doing the upgrade from the terminal. I might still get the errors...

Comment: I doubt you'll get the same errors. They all seem to be to do with the UI.

Comment: Processing was halted because there were too many errors.

Upgrade complete 

The upgrade has completed but there were errors during the upgrade 
process. 

To continue please press [ENTER]
And enter brings back the tonkku@ubuntu:~$
How can I upgrade?